# Geo Location with javascript 

Tags: javascript, django, geo

I am trying to geolocate a user then present him a driving path to my location using django and javascript.
The js i am using is over here: http://github.com/gvkalra/random/blob/master/templates/home/index.html

If to the geolocation prompt I say "Share my location", the system is not working. I am unable to figure out why ..... Please help me .... Am new to js

Comment: can you please submit a snippet of your code ?

Comment: are you getting the user's lat/lng at least?

Answer (score 0):

@Dani I have given the link, anyways

here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/HtNq52aV

@Anurag yes i am getting them

Comment: ok ok .... i don't know why n how, but it is not working... i didn't change the source code though! ..